# MVC3 Ajax Get String and post it back

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, get

on MVC3 Page load i have a String in a Model which is should be the JSONObj.

```
private string CreateJSONObj(Model model)
{ return "{ name: 'test', Items: [{ test: 1 }, { test: 2 }]"; }

Model.jsonModel = CreateJSONObj(model);
```

Now i want to implement it in my page:

```
<script>var jsModel = eval('@Model.jsonModel');

var jsonModel = $.toJSON(jsModel);
$.ajax({
        url: 'Page/SetJSON/',
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonModel,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            $('#test').html('Saved').fadeIn(),
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#test").html("error"),
        }
        });</script>
```

But the Controller gets a null Object. If i write the jsonstring into the script everthing is fine.

Should i use eval? But var jsModel = eval('@Model.jsonModel'); has no effect. What is wrong? :-)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a `CreateJSONObj` method or a `jsonModel` property on your model. In order to use it in the view you could simply use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class which will convert the server side model object into a javascript object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsModel = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SetJSON", "Page")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsModel),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function () {
            $('#test').html('Saved').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#test').html('error');
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will successfully send the model to the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetJSON(Model model)
{
    ...
}
```

where the `Model` class contains all the necessary information:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Test { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller:

```
public class PageController: Controller
{
    // Used to render the view
    public class Index()
    {
        var model = new Model
        {
            Name = "Test",
            Items = new[]
            {
                new Item { Test = 1 },
                new Item { Test = 2 },
            }
        };    
        return View(model);
    }

    // Used to handle the AJAX POST request
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetJSON(Model model)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```